# Limits of an Integration with Probability Density

Tags: calculus, probability, limits, definite-integrals, density-function

Let $X$ be random variable equipped with a density function $f_X$. I was bothering with   the following equality.

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_x^{x+h}f_X(t)dt = f_X(x)
$$

I don't see clearly why the above equality holds. This seems to me a bit like applying "fundamental theorem of calculus" but not quite sure how to massage it into the right looking. Any suggestion is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: It is indeed the fundamental theorem of calculus. The result holds if $f_X$ is continuous at $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac1h\int_{x}^{x+h}f_X(x)\ dx=\frac{P(x\leq X\leq x+h)}{h}=$$
$$=\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}h$$

and

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}h=F_X'(x)=f_X(x)$$

if the density exists; and it does.

Comment: Ah! I see it now. Thank you so much.